# Undefined variable in Laravel Insert Statement

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm currently learning laravel, not entirely sure what the meaning of the undefined variable means within my SQL statement:

my statement is:

```
DB::statement('INSERT INTO insert_user (firstname, lastname, email, telephone) VALUES (?)', [$firstname], [$lastname], [$email], [$telephone]);
            echo 'We will be in touch when the project is underway';
}
```

error is:

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined variable: firstname
```

The way I have determined the variables are below, which hopefully is the the correct way:

My Controller:

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
//Access Modifiers & Properties

    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $email;
    private $telephone;

    public function index()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }

//Access Modifiers & Properties

    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $email;
    private $telephone;

    public function index()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }

//Insert Methods

public function insertContact ($firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone) //
{
   $this->firstname = $firstname;
    $this->lastname = $lastname;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->telephone = $telephone;

        //$contact = new ContactController;
            //DB::insert('INSERT INTO insert_user (firstname, lastname, email, telephone) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :telephone)', ['firstname' => $firstname,'lastname' => $lastname,'email' => $email, 'telephone' => $telephone]);
            DB::statement('INSERT INTO insert_user (firstname, lastname, email, telephone) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :telephone)', ['firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname, 'email' => $email, 'telephone' => $telephone]);
            echo 'We will be in touch when the project is underway';
}
}
```

Comment: Your `$firstname` is not determined or null

Comment: thanks, any idea where I would determine this?

Comment: show full code.

Comment: We're going need to see the full code to determine where your variables are being defined (or if they are). Also, why not use `eloquent` to save this?

Comment: @fyroc please see the updated code above

Comment: Do you know which code line is the problem occurring at? You can check out storage/logs/laravel.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined variable means the variable does not exist (a null value wouldn't be a problem as long as the statement allows nullable values). Most probably, your variable does not exist either due to scope issues, typos or something else that we can't determine from your snippet.

Besides that, your query is not correct and should be changed to the following. Moreover, instead of running a `statement` you could use an `insert`:

```
DB::insert('INSERT INTO insert_user (firstname, lastname, email, telephone) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [$firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone]);
```

You can also use name bindings instead of the `?` for readability:

```
DB::insert('INSERT INTO insert_user (firstname, lastname, email, telephone) 
    VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :telephone)', ['firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname, 'email' => $email, 'telephone' => $telephone]);
```

This is also the same as above (if the table has an auto-incrementing id, this method returns it):

```
$id = DB::table('insert_user')->insert([
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'email' => $email,
    'telephone' => $telephone
]);
```

Eloquent can be used to achieve the same thing:

```
$model = App\InsertUser::create([
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'email' => $email,
    'telephone' => $telephone
]);
```

<sub>Edit: Syntax changes</sub>

### Edit (per author's comment)

Since this is a public function, I suspect is also a route action. Assuming this is a POST, your route may have misconfigured parameters.

Either change your route parameters to `/{firstname}/{lastname}/{email}/{telephone}` in your decleration inside `web/api.php` or (better) inject the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object in the `insertContact` function and access the values like this: `$request->input('firstname')` etc...

More info is available in the official documentation for [request values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests) and [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters).

Comment: I have updated my code above, you can see the controller above in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are not getting the forms `Request` in the controller. The `Request` is what grabs the POST data. Also, I suggest using eloquent.

```
public function insertContact (Request $request) //
{
     $model = App\InsertUser::create([
       'firstname' => $request->firstname,
       'lastname' => $request->lastname,
       'email' => $request->email,
       'telephone' => $request->telephone
    ]);
}
```

Comment: DB::table('insert_user')->insert([

                    'firstname' => $request->firstname,
                    'lastname' => $request->lastname,
                    'email' => $request->email,
                    'telephone' => $request->telephone,
                ]);

Comment: I basically did this and defined them that way, thanks for your inputs appreciated the help.

Comment: @DeveloperJay please mark this as the best answer then.

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
`DB::statement('INSERT INTO insert_user (firstname, lastname, email, telephone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [$firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone]);`